# Android - Detect if activity start due to screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

Is there a sane way by which we can detect if an `Activity` is restarted due to screen orientation change or it is merely started because an `Intent` has arrived?

In my application, I have a `FragmentActivity` that holds two `Fragment`s. The users can navigate between these `Fragment`s using the `ActionBar` tabs.
There's also provision that an `Intent` to this `Activity` can carry an `EXTRA` that can hold an indicator to the default tab to be selected. So, when the `Activity` starts, any of the two tabs can be selected by default determined by the `EXTRA`.

The problem occurs when the user navigates to the other tab from the default selected tab. On rotation change, the `Activity` is restarted making the default tab to be selected from `EXTRA` again and not selecting the tab the user navigated to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the selected tab name through onSaveInstanceState

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tabName", "tab1");
}
```

and get the value in onCreate

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String tabname = savedInstanceState.getString("tabName");
        }
```

Comment: This maybe solves a @jaibatrik's problem,but doesnt answer the primary question: Detect if activity start due to screen orientation change

Comment: If you find the `savedInstanceState` as not `null`, that would mean the Activity has restarted due to orientation change.

Comment: @jaibatrik True, never paid attention to it though. Its true.

Comment: and, savedInstanceState will not be `null` even if we don't set anything in it?

Comment: If you set anything, then it will be not null and it will be null otherwise.

Comment: @jaibatrik `savedInstanceState` might be non-null in other situations as well... for example, if the Android OS killed the activity when it was in the background because memory was low. This is not the same thing as a "configuration change".

Comment: Yes, the proper test would be to check if `tabName` is null or not.

Comment: You can store the boolean value of `activity.isChangingConfigurations` in savedInstanceState.

Answer (score -1):

Create a global flag indicating which tab the user is in currently.

Update this in your `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods.

You can set it again from your `onStart()` and `onRestart()` methods.

For further reference check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

If you don’t like Android’s default method for handling screen rotation, you can take matters into your own hands. Set the android:ConfigChanges attribute for your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="orientation"
      >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Here, the orientation flag in android:configChanges tells the system that the Activity wishes to handle rotation on its own. Android will invoke the onConfigurationChanged() method of your Activity instead, which allow you to handle the screen rotation yourself. It will no longer kill and restart your Activity.